# ¿Como colocar un scroll dependiente del tamaño de un menu con CSS?

Tags: html, css, html5, bootstrap

Tengo un menu que tiene `position: absolute`, en donde la altura del menu va  dependiendo de la cantidad de items que haya. Generalmente, los contenidos se me muestra bien, pero cuando hay demasiado hacia abajo, aparace un espacio en blanco, debajo del menu que se ve mal(algo parecido):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">ejemplo</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

******CSS*****

```
#navbarSupportedContent{
    margin-top:10px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

****html******

```
<div id="content">
   TITULO
   TABLAS .....
   informacion y contenidos
</div>
```

La idea es que cuando el contenido de la pagina, sobrepase la altura del menu, aparezca un scroll, en caso contrario, el scroll no se muestre, es decir, una cosa similar a esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien tiene alguna idea, o ejemplo se lo agradecería.
Saludos.

Comment: Podrías cambiar la posición del menú a `sticky` con un `height: 100vh`. Haciendo esto no debes preocuparte por el scroll del `body` si esta en `overflow: auto`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En cuanto a estructuración y maquetación de layouts yo siempre recomiendo el uso de `flexbox` (si no se necesita compatibilidad con IE9 o anteriores).
Para tu caso, `flexbox` se debería aplicar a un elemento **(wrapper)** que contenga tanto el `nav` como el `content` y sería algo como:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="nav">
        <!-- ... -->        
    </ul>
    <div class="content">
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
/* Envoltura */
.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;    
}

/* Elementos hijo directamente (que serían: nav y content) */
.wrapper > * {
    overflow: auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

Te voy a dejar [este ejemplo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-754ajz?file=style.css) (y no la solución directamente) para que juegues con él y así lo entiendas mejor y lo adaptes a tu caso.

[Más sobre flexbox (inglés)](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score -1):

Tú ve ese error una vez, prueba dándole al body y html esto:

```
body,html{
    width:100%;
    heigth:100%;
}
```

Te digo esto, para que el menú lateral coja todo el alto, para que así no tengas, que poner ese scroll ;), entonces a tu contenedor menú, tendrías que dar le todo el alto, osea que ocupe el 100% del alto;
Esperó qué te sirva.

Answer (score -1):

Agrega las siguientes lineas en tu css

```
body,html{heigth:100vh;}

#navbarSupportedContent{height: 100vh;}
```

con el 100vh forza al elemento a ocupar todo el alto del contendor y el contenedor body y html también ocupa todo el alto con el 100vh

Comment: Hola dav1dth, Agrega una explicación del código por favor ¿Que hace o en que ayuda a resolver el problema planteado por el OP?, te sugerimos realizar tus respuestas en base a [answer], saludos.

Comment: Que tal Elenasys ya edite la respuesta no puse desde el inicio porque hace rato en otra pregunta yo ponía así de agrega esto en css y esto en tu js y un usuario me puso que era redundante decirlo que al ver el código ya se sabe donde debe de ir